# Adjust font-size to the width of the div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following html:

```
<div class="title">
    <span>Some title</span>
</div>
```

and i need the `font-size` of the span to be relative to the width of the div. I tried it with the `vw`:

```
.title span {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 5vw;
}
```

but that isnt the solution because the container for the viewport does not seem to be the `<div class="title">` because when i set it to `5vw` for example it is much larger than my `<div>`.

So how can i set a `font-size` of a `<span>` relative to it's parent div.

Comment: You cannot using CSS alone. You could use javascript, but first take a look at [fittext.js](http://fittextjs.com/).

Comment: what do you mean relevant to the div?

Comment: The viewport unit refers to the window size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well.. this should get you there, right?

Write a simple if / else condition based on element [.width](http://api.jquery.com/width/) !

```
if($('div.banner').width() < 800)
{
 //do first
 $('div.banner').css("font-size", newFontSize);
}
else
{
 // do else
}
```